# 'No default language could be detected for this app' with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

I have a Flask app which runs fine locally with Heroku. However when I try `git push heroku master` I get the error `No default language could be detected for this app.`

Setting the buildpack manually with `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python` and then trying to push also gives an error: `Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz buildpack`.

Is this error because I have file types other than Python in my project? The project structure is below, and the `data` folder contains several different file types.

```
app/
    data/
    model/
    utils/
static/
    css/
templates/
Procfile
README.md
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
run.py
```

If so, what's the recommended course of action here?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I switched to `master` branch I was able to push successfully.